# Hibernate, several queries in one transaction - NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a pretty  complicated method `addOrder()` which contains several queries in one transaction, and one session:

simplistically without business logic  it's look like this:

**DBservice**

```
     public boolean addOrder( List<Items> item, String custumerName, double sum){
       try{
          session = sesinfactory.openSession();
           tx = session.beginTransaction();
        ....

          Dao dao = new Dao(session);
          Custumer custumer = dao.getCustomerByName(custumerName);
          List<Items> tocheckItems = dao.getItems(item);
        ...
           dao.updateItems(itemsToUpdate);

            if (custumer != null) {
                 if (custumer.getCoins() >= sum) {
                       for (Items items : item) {
                            custumer.addItem(items);
                       }
                 }
             } 
          dao.updateCustomerForOrder(custumer);
          tx.commit();
      }
        .....
        finally {
                    if (session != null){
                        session.close();
                     }
                 }
      }
```

**Dao**

```
public class Dao {
    private Session session;
    public Dao(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }


          public void  updateItems(List<Items> itemsName) {
                int i=0;
                for (Items s : itemsName) {

                    session.update(s);
                    if( i % 50 == 0 ) { // Same as the JDBC batch size
                        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
                        session.flush();
                        session.clear();
                    }
                    i++;
                }

            }

          public void updateCustomerForOrder(Custumer custumer) {
                session.update(custumer);
            }
    }
```

while executing method `addOrder()` I'm getting NullPointerExeption in

`updateCustomerForOrder()`, Debug mode shows that `session` and `customer` objects that passed in this method
are not null, so I'm a bit confused whats wrong?
full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(AbstractTypeDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getHashCode(EntityType.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.generateHashCode(EntityKey.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.generateEntityKey(AbstractSessionImpl.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:726)
    at org.CoinsShop.DataBase.Dao.updateCustomerForOrder(Dao.java:129)
    at org.CoinsShop.DataBase.DbService.addOrder(DbService.java:286)
    at org.CoinsShop.bussinessLayer.BusineesLayer.handleOrder(BusineesLayer.java:61)
    at org.CoinsShop.bussinessLayer.BusineesLayer$handleOrder.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.CoinsShop.DataBase.DbServiceTest.addOrder2Test(DbServiceTest.groovy:337)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

**UPD.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Items")
public class Items implements  Serializable,Comparable<Items>  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="price")
    private double price;
    @Column(name="count")
    private int count;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Order> orders = new LinkedList<Order>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Items items = (Items) o;

        return name.equals(items.name);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        long temp;
        result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(price);
        result = 31 * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + count;
        result = 31 * result + (orders != null ? orders.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Items o) {
        return getName().compareTo(o.getName());

    }
}
```

Comment: Mostly possible that your `Item` class has wrong implementation of `hashCode()` method. Can you show its code?

Comment: What happens if you remove the flush/clear for a test?  Is the transaction too big then?  I've not had to do this and it seems that you're taking over for the management that Hibernate would be doing.

Comment: The Null pointer is coming on the extractHashCode on the entity. in your case entity is Item class. Can you put the implementation details of the item class along with how hashcode method is overloaded ?

Comment: post has been updated

Comment: Sorry, how did you figure out that wrong hash code relate to Items class?
Exception occurres when update CustomerforOrder executes with Customer object as  input parameter, and I don't see any reference on items in stack trace)

Answer (score 0):

this post helped  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8576809/5526080

I need to add to customer updated items, not origin

```
 dao.updateItems(itemsToUpdate);

            if (custumer != null) {
                 if (custumer.getCoins() >= sum) {
                       for (Items items : itemsToUpdate) {
                            custumer.addItem(itemsToUpdate);
                       }
                 }
             } 
          dao.updateCustomerForOrder(custumer);
          tx.commit();
```

otherwise the items hash codes are different, as I understood